# MVC Dropdownlistfor<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I just started a project in MVC. I am new to MVC asp.net. I want to add a dropdown list box like I used to add in asp.net.

### code glimpses in asp.net for Dropdownlist box

```
<asp:Dropdownlist ID="ddlCity" runat="server">
<asp:ItemList Text="Kolkatta" Value="1"/>
<asp:ItemList Text="New Delhi" Value="2"/>
<asp:ItemList Text="Mumbai" Value="3"/>
<asp:ItemList Text="chennai" Value="4"/>
<asp:ItemList Text="Hydrabad" Value="5"/>
</asp:Dropdownlist>
```

I want a dropdown list box in that manner....  meaning, now I need to create a model and controller for that. Suppose I have already have a view named "Employee Entry Form" and I need to add one dropdown list only on that page. 
I do not want to create a model for this dropdown list; I only need it on this page.

Answer (score 37):

The values for the dropdownlist should be in your *existing* view model:

```
public class WhateverViewModel
{
    // All of your current viewmodel fields here
    public string SelectedCity { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> CityOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Populate these in your controller with whatever values you want (where SelectedCity is your numerical ID), then do the following in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCity,
    new SelectList(Model.CityOptions, "Key", "Value", Model.SelectedCity))
```

If your values never change, you could hardcode them as a `static` member of your view model and then do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCity,
    new SelectList(WhateverViewModel.CityOptions, "Key", "Value", Model.SelectedCity))
```

Either way, this is data for this view, so it belongs in your view model. If you're not using view models and this view is directly tied to a domain entity; you should be using them and now is as good a time as any to start.

Comment: There are definitely cases where, for performance reasons, you may want to create a specialized model for a given drop down.  This would be tied to an actual database view designed to return only those specific key/value pairs needed for the drop down, and in most cases, the other keys used to pre-filter the drop down list.  Ant, I realize your view model design allows for this, but I thought it helpful to explicitly call it out based on the original question.

Answer (score 8):

You can also follow another approach which is to collect all dropdown lists in 1 helper class and return theses lists each with a static function.

**Ex.
Dropdown helper class**

```
namespace Asko.Web.Mvc.Infrastructure.Utils
{
    public static class DropdownHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllCategories()
        {
            var categories = category.GetAll();
            return categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.categoryName, Value = x.categoryId.ToString()}));
        }
    }
}
```

**And here you are going to use it in the page:**

```
<td style="width: 150px;">
      <b>Category: </b>
      <br>
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, DropdownHelper.GetAllCategories())
</td>
```

Comment: DropDownHelper dose not exist in current context why ?

Comment: I would rather avoid Invoking a method that causes Database round-trip from a view. View should have everything ready in the Model, and data retrieval should be managed by Controller.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the usage of model, you may simply use a ViewBag. in your action:

```
ViewBag.DirectorId = new SelectList(ListOfItemsToAdd, "dataValueField", "dataTextField", movie.DirectorId);
```

and in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("VariableNameToPost", ViewBag.DirectorId) //for asp.net view engine %> 
@Html.DropDownList("VariableNameToPost", ViewBag.DirectorId) // for razor view engine
```

and the action that would accept the variable would then have something like this:

```
public ActionResult theAction(string VariableNameToPost){...}
```

refferences:

- [Select List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
- [Drop Down List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much... for your instant reply. i solved it my self. i found that you added answer here which is copy paste.

Comment: It is ok for your time and answer... but i did my self and it is more easy and accurate than you...

Comment: @Shahnawaz could you post the solution and mark it as an answer so that other developers, that are having similar issues, could find it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a drop down directly on view regardless of controller and model then you can create it using following code

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", 
  new SelectList(new [] { new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "IT", 0 ), new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "HR", 1 )},"Value", "Key"))
```