# How to show data in textbox on dropdown selection using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am very much new in MVC. I am trying to show data in textbox on selection of value in dropdown.

Code for "Create View":

```
    @model CRUD_using_LinQ_to_SQL_in_MVC.Models.OtdModelClass
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";}
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Create</legend>

    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        Server Type:
    <//div>
    <div>
    <select name="Server Type" id="ServerType">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="1">Internet</option>
        <option value="2">Lease</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MemberCode, new { maxlength="6"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoginID, new { maxlength = "6" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OTDPassword)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OTDPassword, new { maxlength = "7" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OTDPassword)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BBSID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BBSID, new { maxlength = "6" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BBSID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IPAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IPAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IPAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServerType)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ServerType)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServerType)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OTDStatus)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OTDStatus)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OTDStatus)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RemoteIP)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RemoteIP)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RemoteIP)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RemotePort)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RemotePort)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RemotePort)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AllowDownload)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AllowDownload)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AllowDownload)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OTDTimeStamp)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OTDTimeStamp)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OTDTimeStamp)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberType)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MemberType)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberType)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EQ)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EQ)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EQ)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EQD)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EQD)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EQD)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BFX)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BFX)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BFX)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SLB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SLB)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SLB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Others)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Others)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Others)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>}<div>    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</div>
```

Here when user select option "Internet" in server type then "Remote IP" and "Remote Port" fields should get autofilled with respective values.
I searched a lot on internet but i didnt get proper solution for this.
Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC Dropdownlistfor<>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019272/mvc-dropdownlistfor)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're coding the drop down yourself in HTML. What you should be using is the [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx) method in MVC.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17021672/1861513) can provide you with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below,
1. Create a jquery onchange event for the dropdown you mentioned.
2. Get the selected value.
3. Create a new action method with Json return type and input parameter as string named ServerType. And query the database to get the RemoteIp and Remoteport values based on the server type.
4. In the jquery onchange event do a ajax call to the action method created in step 3.
5. Form the json data as "{"ServerType": "Your selected dropdown value"}.
6. In the ajax success method assign the text box with the respective data from the success method result.

Hope you know using jquery better using ajax call. You may use the Html.Dropdownfor() control as the other answer suggests. Please let me know if any information required.